# "No irq handler for vector (irq -1)" after hibernation

Tags: linux, hibernate, irq, hibernation

Resuming from hibernation messages like these are printed to all terminals:

```
Message from syslogd@Ildjarn at Apr  8 08:11:14 ...
 kernel:[24089.310964] do_IRQ: 0.82 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)

Message from syslogd@Ildjarn at Apr  8 08:16:14 ...
 kernel:[24388.800124] do_IRQ: 0.82 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)

Message from syslogd@Ildjarn at Apr  8 08:21:15 ...
 kernel:[24688.289279] do_IRQ: 0.82 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)
```

I have tried passing `pci=noaer,nomsi` to kernel but the messages remain after hibernation.

How can i stop the messages or atleast route them elsewhere ?

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8                1208  3 
cifs                  258832  4 
parport_pc             18855  0 
ppdev                   5030  0 
lp                      7462  0 
parport                27954  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
acpi_cpufreq            5571  1 
sco                     7209  2 
bridge                 39630  0 
stp                     1440  1 bridge
bnep                    9427  2 
cpufreq_stats           2659  0 
rfcomm                 29613  0 
l2cap                  24736  4 bnep,rfcomm
crc16                   1319  1 l2cap
cpufreq_userspace       1992  0 
bluetooth              41827  6 sco,bnep,rfcomm,l2cap
cpufreq_powersave        902  0 
rfkill                 13044  3 bluetooth
cpufreq_conservative     5162  0 
binfmt_misc             6431  1 
fuse                   50892  1 
loop                   11799  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   235602  0 
snd_hda_intel          20035  1 
snd_hda_codec          54244  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep               5380  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                60503  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                42881  0 
snd_timer              15582  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
usbhid                 33292  0 
snd_seq_device          4493  1 snd_seq
ftdi_sio               33768  1 
hid                    63257  1 usbhid
usbserial              27676  3 ftdi_sio
snd                    46446  10 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
nvidia              10670090  28 
i2c_i801                7830  0 
asus_atk0110            7670  0 
soundcore               4598  1 snd
psmouse                49937  0 
pcspkr                  1699  0 
evdev                   7352  8 
snd_page_alloc          6249  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw               3752  0 
i2c_core               15819  2 nvidia,i2c_i801
button                  4650  0 
processor              29935  5 acpi_cpufreq
usb_storage            39961  0 
xfs                   435351  2 
exportfs                3170  1 xfs
sg                     18744  0 
sd_mod                 29921  4 
sr_mod                 12602  0 
crc_t10dif              1276  1 sd_mod
cdrom                  29415  1 sr_mod
ata_generic             3047  0 
ehci_hcd               32081  0 
ata_piix               21124  3 
pata_jmicron            2280  0 
usbcore               122386  6 usbhid,ftdi_sio,usbserial,usb_storage,ehci_hcd
nls_base                6377  3 nls_utf8,cifs,usbcore
libata                133632  3 ata_generic,ata_piix,pata_jmicron
scsi_mod              122149  5 usb_storage,sg,sd_mod,sr_mod,libata
r8169                  29263  0 
mii                     3210  1 r8169
thermal                11674  0 
thermal_sys            11942  2 processor,thermal
```

uname -a:

```
Linux Ildjarn 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 21:35:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -v:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] #00 [0000]

00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: f4000000-f7efffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e4000000-00000000efffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [160] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=0 Len=00c 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 0043:0083
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0000 Rev=0 Len=000 

00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 0043:0083
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0000 Rev=0 Len=000 

00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Device 0043:0083
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0000 Rev=0 Len=000 

00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at f3fff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f3ffe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8435
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at f3ff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: e0000000-e01fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0200000-00000000e03fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0400000-e05fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0600000-00000000e07fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0800000-e09fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0a00000-00000000e0bfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7f00000-f7ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2f00000-00000000f2ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0c00000-e0dfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0e00000-00000000e0ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f3ffd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at ac00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at a880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at a800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at a480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at a400 [size=16]
    I/O ports at a080 [size=16]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at f3ffc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 0400 [size=32]

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8383
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at bc00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at b880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at b800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at b480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at b400 [size=16]
    I/O ports at b080 [size=16]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [GeForce 450 GTS] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 1194
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at e4000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7e00000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting 
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0be9 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 1194
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at f7efc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785TD Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    I/O ports at d800 [size=256]
    Memory at f2fff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f2ff8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at f7fe0000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

06:00.0 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB368 IDE controller (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 824f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at ec00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e400 [size=16]
    Capabilities: [68] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 01
    Kernel driver in use: pata_jmicron
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the kernel-option `noirqdebug`. This might help here...

BTW: What devices use which irqs before and after hybernation?

Is anything else wrong - are some devices disabled after hybernate?

After googling around I found this: [This looks like your problem](http://pygospa.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/no-irq-handler_aka_problems-with-my-pcie-port/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have since upgraded to a newer kernel which doesn't have the same but a different problem. pm-hibernate tries to go into hibernation but is stuck, waiting for something. r8169 kernel module seems to be the cause. If I rmmod it before hibernate everything works as expected. I suspect the troubles is foremost that the wrong module is loaded. I have "03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)" but r8169 is loaded.