# linux hibernate working but slow

Tags: linux, kernel, electrical-power, intel, hibernation

I've set up pm-hibernate on AMD and one older Intel platform. But this perticular one is giving me more trouble than usual. Issuing pm-hibernate works but hangs for a long time before finally shutting down.

In the dmesg below it waits for maybe 15 seconds before following line is printed:

[   78.296348] PM: Creating hibernation image:

In the same way, resume has a long wait after:

[   80.401171] usb 2-1.5: reset low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3

It's not that I can't wait those 15 seconds. But I'd like to know why it behaves like this. What could provide more information on what the kernel / OS  is waiting for?

With the same computer and a standard kernel from Debian squeeze, it also works, is faster but have other issues such as ["No irq handler for vector (irq -1)" after hibernation](https://serverfault.com/questions/257226/no-irq-handler-for-vector-irq-1-after-hibernation)

The kernel i'm trying to use is is an official unpatched kernel 2.6.38.4 from kernel.org

Kernel config:
http://www.ideone.com/Hrmah

dmesg:

```
[   77.830657] ftdi_sio 1-1.6:1.0: device disconnected
[   77.830694] ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[   77.830703] ftdi_sio 1-1.6:1.1: device disconnected
[   77.831735] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link down
[   77.831861] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT D disabled
[   77.831886] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: PCI INT D disabled
[   77.932716] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A disabled
[   77.932785] ACPI handle has no context!
[   78.245752] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: PCI INT B disabled
[   78.245840] ACPI handle has no context!
[   78.256889] PM: freeze of devices complete after 427.118 msecs
[   78.257710] PM: late freeze of devices complete after 0.770 msecs
[   78.258007] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[   78.258297] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[   78.260491] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[   78.274043] CPU 1 is now offline
[   78.288013] CPU 2 is now offline
[   78.295913] CPU 3 is now offline
[   78.296220] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[   78.296348] PM: Creating hibernation image:
[   78.347165] PM: Need to copy 155463 pages
[   78.296367] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[   78.296869] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[   78.296930] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[   78.298285] Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[   78.391182] Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #1
[   78.403406] CPU1 is up
[   78.403683] Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[   78.495085] Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #2
[   78.507422] CPU2 is up
[   78.507812] Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[   78.600885] Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #3
[   78.613239] CPU3 is up
[   78.614809] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[   78.625827] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: BAR 0: set to [mem 0xf3ff8000-0xf3ffbfff 64bit] (PCI address [0xf3ff8000-0xf3ffbfff])
[   78.625925] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x100, writing 0x103)
[   78.625938] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x0, writing 0x8)
[   78.625943] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100102)
[   78.626210] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2b00003, writing 0x2b00007)
[   78.626251] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2b00001, writing 0x2b00005)
[   78.626271] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0xc (was 0xf7e00000, writing 0x0)
[   78.626280] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x800008, writing 0x800000)
[   78.626283] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100107, writing 0x100007)
[   78.636917] PM: early restore of devices complete after 21.851 msecs
[   78.666198] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.666216] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[   78.666238] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[   78.666246] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.666249] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.666263] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[   78.666273] pci 0000:00:1e.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.666284] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT D -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[   78.670145] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.670149] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: PCI INT D -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[   78.670152] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 32 is not supported
[   78.670154] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.670166] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   78.670170] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
[   78.674350] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 32 is not supported
[   78.674655] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[   78.990007] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   78.997227] usb 1-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
[   79.141031] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   79.179132] ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:45:00:00:00:a0 (unknown) filtered out
[   79.179199] ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:0c:00:00:00:a0 (unknown) filtered out
[   79.192661] ata4.00: ACPI cmd c6/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (unknown) succeeded
[   79.192668] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (unknown) filtered out
[   79.212890] usb 2-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
[   79.252963] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   79.303578] ata2.00: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   79.303642] ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   79.399746] usb 1-1.6: reset full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[   79.454577] ata1.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[   79.454649] ata1.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   79.454706] ata1.01: link offline, clearing class 3 to NONE
[   79.457722] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:45:00:00:00:a0 (unknown) filtered out
[   79.457789] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:0c:00:00:00:a0 (unknown) filtered out
[   79.457850] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (unknown) filtered out
[   79.463708] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   79.547518] usb 1-1.1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[   79.883974] usb 2-1.6: reset low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[   80.401171] usb 2-1.5: reset low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[  138.658306] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: unable to apply firmware patch
[  138.660715] PM: restore of devices complete after 60090.145 msecs
[  138.660799] ftdi_sio 1-1.6:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  138.660877] usb 1-1.6: Detected FT2232C
[  138.660928] usb 1-1.6: Number of endpoints 2
[  138.660980] usb 1-1.6: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[  138.661032] usb 1-1.6: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[  138.661085] usb 1-1.6: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[  138.661474] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link down
[  138.661874] usb 1-1.6: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  138.661967] ftdi_sio 1-1.6:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  138.662192] usb 1-1.6: Detected FT2232C
[  138.662244] usb 1-1.6: Number of endpoints 2
[  138.662296] usb 1-1.6: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[  138.662348] usb 1-1.6: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[  138.662401] usb 1-1.6: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[  138.662865] usb 1-1.6: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  138.664227] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link down
[  138.682700] Restarting tasks ... 
[  138.684882] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, address 3
[  138.685540] done.
[  138.872950] usb 2-1.5: new low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[  138.952714] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0084
[  138.952721] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  138.952725] usb 2-1.5: Product: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse 
[  138.952729] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Microsoft 
[  138.956350] input: Microsoft  Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/input/input4
[  138.956419] generic-usb 0003:045E:0084.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft  Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse ] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input0
[  140.344645] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link up
```

http://www.ideone.com/PHhqV

lspci -v:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [GeForce 450 GTS] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0be9 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by doing rmmod r8169 before hibernate. I suspect the wrong module is loaded. lspci says I have "03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)" but "r8169" is loaded.

The device is onboard PCI Express.