# No irq handler for vector - randomly starting after time

Tags: linux-kernel, irq, kernel-debugging

I don't know where to start, so I give some basic information about my system and my observation.

I'm having a Fedora 37 Linux server at home. After some uptime (happens after 3-5 days after booting), it starts to write following messages to terminal and `dmesg` (in an interval of ~10sec):

```
[181648.485653] __common_interrupt: 9.38 No irq handler for vector
[181650.533159] __common_interrupt: 10.40 No irq handler for vector
...
```

I'm aware of ["No irq handler for vector (irq -1)" after hibernation](https://serverfault.com/questions/257226/no-irq-handler-for-vector-irq-1-after-hibernation), but I'm not hibernating and it just offers to just disable irq-debug (ignoring it).

Many posts I've found googling suggest to just suppress those messages and ignore them. I'm not sure if there is actual a problem (so ignoring would be fine if there is no problem). I do not notice any different behavior and after rebooting the server, it stops for quite some time. I wasn't able to find some useful logs that happen "just before" or any process I'm running. It just happens and I don't know why.

How can I debug it? Where should I start, beside trying to ignore those message?
Main reason is: I'm logging to an expensive flash storage. Flooding with "nonsense" makes me crazy, also flooding my terminal makes it pretty useless.

---

I thought about an BIOS update (currently I can download v1.1a, but I couldn't find any changelog - thank you, Supermicro ...)
It's a Supermicro M11SDV-8C-LN4F (v 1.02)

```bash
$ dmidecode -t bios
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 1.0c
    Release Date: 06/30/2020
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.13
```

```bash
$ uname -r
6.1.6-200.fc37.x86_64
```

```bash
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc 7300 PRO NVMe SSD (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 04)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor (PSP) 3.0 Device
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin USB 3.0 xHCI Compliant Host Controller
06:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
06:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin Cryptographic Coprocessor NTBCCP
06:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

Comment: `I'm having a Fedora 37 Linux server at home` -> off topic. Voting to migrate the question to [unix.se].

Comment: Sorry, probably I've misspelled this. It's not a home server, it's my business server, ups-backed, hosting nextcloud, grafana, websites, ... running on kubernetes. It's just located at home ... new-normal, you know :-D